# Angular: preconstructed object vs template getters

Tags: angular, performance, typescript, performance-testing

I've long been wondering whether to use a template full of getters, or just preconstruct the entire object with a resolver, and I can't really seem to find a clear answer anywhere.

I've created two simplified scenarios below.

Currently, I'm always using scenario 1, but as soon as the app/program becomes more complex, I notice (huge) performance drops, therefore I'm thinking about using scenario 2 from now on.

---

**Scenario 1: Getter functions**

- Pro: You only get/use whatever you need in your current template. Adding new getters does not require you to update your interfaces.
- Con: Impact on performance when having hundreds/thousands of getters in a single template (I think).

Code:

```
var devices = ['desktop', 'tablet', 'mobile'];

var icons = {
    desktop: 'icon-desktop',
    tablet: 'icon-tablet',
    mobile: 'icon-mobile'
}

var translations = {
    desktop: 'Desktop',
    tablet: 'Tablet',
    mobile: 'Mobile'
}

getIcon(item: string): string {
    return icons(type);
}

getTranslation(item: string): string {
    return translations(type);
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="device in devices">
    <i [class]="getIcon(device)"></i>
    <span>{{ getTranslation(device) }}</span>
</div>
```

---

**Scenario 2: Preconstruct the object**

- Pro: With `resolve`, it's easy to preconstruct the entire object, thus skipping all the getters in my template.
- Pro: The object never changes, therefore Angular does not have to 'watch' it.
- Con: The object can become huge, and a lot of properties may never be used.

Code:

```
var devices = [
    {
        item: 'desktop',
        translation: 'Desktop',
        icon: 'icon-desktop'
    },
    {
        item: 'tablet',
        translation: 'Tablet',
        icon: 'icon-tablet'
    },
    {
        item: 'mobile',
        translation: 'Mobile',
        icon: 'icon-mobile'
    }
]
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="device in devices">
    <i [class]="device.icon"></i>
    <span>{{ device.translation }}</span>
</div>
```

---

Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of each scenario, and why? What about performance (my main question)? Personal preference or experience?

Comment: It seems like you already know the pros/cons and performance based on what you have listed. Personal preference questions are considered off topic.

Comment: Those are just assumptions. I'm no expert on how this functions 'behind the scenes'. Also thanks for pointing out, I've changed it to personal *experience*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTranslation(device)` will be called on each change detection cycle. This provides performance overhead but it is insignificant, as long as `getTranslation` itself isn't costly.

A more conventional way is to use a pipe like `{{ device | translation }}`. This can be *pure pipe* which is more efficient. But if the language is supposed to be changed dynamically, the pipe should be impure, because the expression evaluates to new value even if `device` value is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards *pure pipes*. I'm going to do some research on those!

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal I added some details on pure/impure pipe. It can be pure pipe in your case, but only as long as you don't change the language dynamically after the app was initialized.

Comment: Well, I've been using them a lot lately, for all kinds of stuff, so I know how they work. I just remembered this answer from a while ago, and decided to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using getters invoked in the template will be called near 100% more than a function. You can test this by inserting a `console.count()` into each.

Depending on your app or component using the `OnPush` change detection strategy which will drastically cut the calls.

Comment: I never knew about `OnPush`, seems very useful, thanks!